# Redshift : convert UTC to Pacific time including Daylight savings, Which to use PST or PDT?

Tags: sql, timezone, amazon-redshift, timezone-offset

I have a table, timestamp as column name which is in UTC time, I need to convert it to Pacific timezone. I have used redshift inbuilt function convert_timezone(utc,pst,"timestamp") but it does not calculate Day light savings time, how do i convert them.?

function that would convert the value from utc to pacific time with/without daylight savings according to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote from the documentation:

> If you specify a time zone using a time zone name, CONVERT_TIMEZONE
> automatically adjusts for Daylight Saving Time (DST), or any other
> local seasonal protocol, such as Summer Time, Standard Time, or Winter
> Time, that is in force for that time zone during the date and time
> specified by 'timestamp'. For example, 'Europe/London' represents UTC
> in the winter and adds one hour in the summer.

so you probably need to be using the name and not the abbreviation

Comment: "US/Pacific" is the name ? do I understand right?
im using
 select convert_timezone('UTC','US/Pacific', '2023-03-25 04:00:45.463')